# I want to show foreign key related data in flask admin view

Tags: flask

When I click on show button of parent table view, it should refer to child table view and display all that foreign key data

```py
def _link_formatter(view, context, model, name):
    link = "<a target='_blank' href='%s' style='margin-left:10px'>%s</a>" % (
        url_for('child_table.index_view', child_id=model.id, url=url_for('child_table.index_view')), "Show Data"
    )
    return Markup(link)

column_formatters = {
    'url': _link_formatter
}
```

the url will be build like:
http://0.0.0.0/admin/child_table/?child_id=184&url=%2Fadmin%child_table%2F